# How to create Android softkeyboard with accented letters á, ó, ú, ý

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I am new to android. I need to create custom keyboard, which consist of all English letters plus 4 accented letters á, ó, ý, ú. This accented letters exist in Android English keyboard, when pressing longer corresponding letter.

I have created keyboard application, which looks like standard English keyboard. 
This is method.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/sybtype_en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method>
```

and this is my keyboard.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="60dp">
    
    
    
    
     <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel="w" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:codes="97"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="á" android:codes="Alt+160"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="s" android:codes="115"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="d" android:codes="100"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="f" android:codes="102"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="g" android:codes="103"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="h" android:codes="104"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="j" android:codes="106"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="k" android:codes="107"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="l" android:codes="108"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="ó" android:codes="162"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:codes="35,64"/>
    </Row>


</Keyboard>
```

By this line I am trying to print Á

```
 <Key android:keyLabel="á" android:codes="Alt+160"/>
```

But this do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the given link. I have found the android keycodes for accented letters:

```
<Key android:keyLabel="á" android:codes="225"/>
<Key android:keyLabel="ó" android:codes="243"/>
<Key android:keyLabel="ý" android:codes="253"/>
<Key android:keyLabel="ú" android:codes="250"/>
```